# Can after trigger be used when there is constant changes in record

Tags: apex, trigger

Hello so I used after trigger to **update** a status field in a record thinking its a after process. Will the trigger get invoked even after the status field is updated after the trigger condition is met once?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have done and where you are stuck. Code snippets (as text, not screenshots) are best. Alternatively, if you are at requirement phase only, showing some effort to research the problem is required. If you don't add details this question is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: Have you read the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that validations and field changes for the current record should be done in a "before" trigger, and changes to related records should be done in an "after" trigger. The reason why you want to perform validations and field updates to the current record in the before trigger is twofold. First, this is much more efficient, as you don't have to go through the [order of operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) twice, and second, you don't have to worry about recursive trigger calls, a consequence of the first reason. That said, there are times and reasons why you may choose an after trigger, although this should be rare.